# Occurrences of same list in an array

Tags: python, numpy

Given the list consists of lists in numpy array. Like the following,

```
array([[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]) and array([[0,0,1], [0,1,0]])
```

I want to count how many elements of the list is equaled using NumPy in a line

Given the above array, I want it to output 1 because only one of them is equaled.

I have tried np.sum(a==b) but it counts the elements in the nested list. Given the arrays, it will return 4 instead of one.

Comment: I don' t know if this is the most efficient way but it worked on this example - `np.count_nonzero((a ==  b).sum(axis=1) == a.shape[1])`

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks